# Lowered dependent variable in one period

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I have a problem with a dependent variable in my model.
The dependent variable is the saving rate which is savings/disposable income. However, disposable income is income - taxes. So the problem is that the disposable income will be lowered in one month of the year, in the period when the individuals are taxed.
What would you suggest to do to handle it?